# pandas.sum() leads to numpy.polyfit unsupported operand error ('method' and 'float) (nx.asarray)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I stumbled upon an issue with the pandas.sum() function:

I have a simple df consisting of 2 columns with float64 dtype.
When I add both columns together with the data.sum(axis=1) function, I can't use the new column in the np.polyfit function.

It gives the following TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'float'

However when I 'manually' add the columns together, np.polyfit doesn't raise an error.
I've checked and can confirm that both methods result in a float64 dtype.

Basic Dataset (data.info()):

```
    Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   usage    100 non-null    float64
 1   standby  100 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

Create both sum columns:

```
data['sum'] = data.sum(axis=1)
data['sum1'] = data.usage + data.standby
```

data.info():

```
   Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   usage    100 non-null    float64
 1   standby  100 non-null    float64
 2   sum      100 non-null    float64
 3   sum1     100 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(4)
```

np.polyfit(data.usage, data.sum, 1) gives the following feedback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.polyfit(data.usage, data.sum, 1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:630, in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    628 order = int(deg) + 1
    629 x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
--> 630 y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0
    632 # check arguments.
    633 if deg < 0:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'float'
```

`np.polyfit(data.usage, data.sum1, 1)` **doesn't throw an error**

*Can anyone explain why both columns with a float64 dtype behave differently?*

Answer (score 1):

`data.sum` is accessing the *method* of summation, rather than the column you're expecting. In other words it's like you've typed `data.sum()` but forgotten the `()`.

If you use `data['sum']` and `data['sum1']` you'll notice you get the correct result both times.